# ASP.NET 5 RequestServices null

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-core

I'm trying to convert my application to ASP.NET 5 RC1 and use Unity for my Dependency Injection. I've been following [this tutorial](http://dzimchuk.net/post/bring-your-own-di-container-to-aspnet-5-unity) and have gotten 90% of the way there.

However, when the page launches I get

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: provider
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be
>   null.  Parameter name: provider
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.Template.TemplateRoute.EnsureLoggers(HttpContext
>   context)

When I look the source code, it's the `context.RequestServices` that is null.

I've looked at various sources that say I need to add `app.UseRequestServices()` to my `Startup` class, but that method no longer exists.

How can I get the HttpContext instances to have `RequestServices` populated? Here's the code I'm doing now to return my `IServiceProvider`

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

    //my class for adding my service registrations
        var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer(Configuration); 
        container.Populate(services);
        return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
    }
```

This is the line of code that is giving me an `ArgumentNullException`

https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Routing/Template/TemplateRoute.cs#L350

```
    private void EnsureLoggers(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (_logger == null)
        {
            //GetRequiredService is an extension method that throws the error because RequestServices is null
            var factory = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
```

Comment: Are you using the RC? It should be setup by default.

Comment: I didn't realize that scoped request services are available during ConfigureServices, only ApplicationServices via IServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider()?

Comment: @davidfowl yes i'm on the RC.

Comment: @armen.shimoon then how can i configure the RequestServices to be available on the line I linked?